# Shortening row or column matrices of constant size

Tags: macros, matrices

I am using many times matrices that have only one row or one column. For example:

```
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 &  2 &  3 \end{pmatrix}
```

So I figured it will be useful to shorten the expression with a `macro` or a `newcommand`. So far I am failing but I don't undestand why. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pmone}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1 \end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\pmtwo}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1 \\ #2\end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\pmTtwo}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1 & #2\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
    $\pmtwo{1,2}$
\end{document}
```

I get the following error: `! Missing $ inserted.`
`<inserted text>`
`$`
`l.12 $ \pmtwo{1,2}$`

However, when I change it into `pmone{1}` it works as expected. Why is that?

(I understand that instead of defining pmone, pmtwo etc there is a way to make it a function with the number as an argument but don't bother with that. I will only use up to 5 or something so no need.)

Comment: Hi, off-topic: mathtools contains also amsmath and it is a robust package.

Comment: @Sebastiano What is a robust package?

Comment: The `mathtools` package it is superior than `amsmath` and it is includes the same. My English language is very poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for `\pmtwo` that works correctly putting the curly brackets. You have two numbers `[2]` i.e. `{#1}` and `{#2}` and `\pmtwo` not want the comma: hence `$\pmtwo{1}{2}$`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}


%\newcommand{\pmone}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1 \end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand{\pmtwo}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}{#1} \\ {#2}\end{pmatrix}}
%\newcommand{\pmTtwo}[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1 & #2\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
    $\pmtwo{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted your answer. I just would like to add that it works even without the brackets in {#i} in the newcommand definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can define `\pmrow{1,2,3}` and `\pmcol{3,4,5,6}` macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\pmrow#1{\def\tmpsep{&}\def\tmp{}\pmrowA #1,,}
\def\pmcol#1{\def\tmpsep{\\}\def\tmp{}\pmrowA #1,,}
\def\pmrowA#1,{\ifx,#1,\begin{pmatrix}\tmp\end{pmatrix}\else
   \ifx\tmp\empty\else\addto\tmp{\tmpsep}\fi\addto\tmp{#1}\expandafter\pmrowA\fi}

\begin{document}
    $\pmrow{1,2,3}$, $\pmcol{3,4,5,6}$
\end{document}
```

I add explanation why `$\pmtwo{1,2}$` given by OP does not work. The `\pmtwo` is defined as macro with two parameters `#1` and `#2` and it usage `$\pmtwo{1,2}$` scans `1.2` to `#1` and `$` to `#2` and the macro expands to

```
\begin{pmatrix}1,2 \\ $\end{pmatrix}
```

We have `$` in the second template in `\halign` primitive. This template is opened by `$` (opens math mode), then given `$` closes it, then the template tries to close math mode by third `$` (but it opens new math mode). Then the end template occurs in math mode. TeX tries to close this math mode by inserting fourth `$` during error recovery. It says about such insertion: `! Missing $ inserted`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I upvoted but accepted the other answer because it's simpler and I can understand it.

Comment: @cgss accepted answer supposes fixed number of elements in the matrix (two). My solution accepts arbitrary number of elements: just write all elements separated by comma. IMHO, it is much more usable for your purposes.

Comment: To be fair, I explicitly mentioned constant size. I think you are answer is really nice. But I have never used half of the commands you used. If you add some explanation I guess people who stumble upon this post will use it/modify it.